# How to distribute Xcode Extension?

Tags: xcode, xcode-extension

I created simple Xcode extension and I want to send it to other team members. I can send them the whole project and let them build it. But how can I export that extension as the app? I just want to send them some file, they double click on it and have that extension installed. Thanks for help!